# Using several passive verbs

Tags: passive-voice, punctuation

I wrote:

> When some grate bars are **displaced, bent or broken,** shadows are increased.

Did I use the verb forms correctly? Did I use commas correctly?

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct. However, the commas are a bit inelegant.

One option is to place the main clause at the begging:

> Shadows are increased when some grate bars are displaced, bent or broken.

Comment: Can it be said in another way: When some grate bars are displaced/bent/broken, shadows are increased.

Comment: That's fine, but I would just write *or* instead of the slash, as in "When some grate bars are displaced or bent or broken, shadows are increased."